# How to get focused edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a set of `EditText`s' in one activity and I have a button that will set the value of the focused `EditText`.

I have tried using:

```
getWindow().getCurrentFocused();
```

But I can't use a `setText()` method on it.

Comment: your question is not clear. Need to see code!

Comment: try to call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus() on your edittext.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to get your EditText from .xml file into your activty, so define an EditText as a global variable:

```
EditText inputTXT;
```

and then write the below code in your onCreate method:

```
inputTXT =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id);
//your_edittext_id is the id of the EditText used in xml
```

And after that you can play with all the functionality of the Edit text, and one of those are to set the text:

```
inputTXT.setText("text");
```

Hope that I've helped you.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"` in your `activity` tag of 
`manifest` xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Let you have a button `mButton` and a edtiText `mEditText`, then you code will be like this-

```
Button mButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
             mEditText.requestFocus();
            }
});
```